# Accessing Sharepoint through CSOM

Tags: 2010, csom

I am trying to access a project SharePoint 2010 site using the below code

```
using (ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxx/proj"))
{
       _clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
       NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");

                _clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

                Web _web = _clientContext.Web;
                _clientContext.Load(_web, website => website.Title);
                _clientContext.Load(_web.Webs);
                _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

However, I keep running into `Internal server error (500)`

I am able to view the site from my browser after providing my credentials.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: just to add, if I don't send my credentials I get a 401. Is there something I need to check with a site admin?

Comment: have you checked this, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/internal-server-error-500-using-managed-client-object-model  he said use the credential in the ClientContext

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: I am already passing the domain credentials or did i misunderstand your comment.

Comment: I am guessing you need a bit more setup to work on ssl perhaps? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71990/ssl-certificate-error-when-using-client-object-model